# how to disable asset pipeline on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

The heroku cedar precompile my assets implicitly, even though I have written:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

How to disable the assets feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the application config isn't available when the slug is compiled. This was recently addressed with http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile but I'm not sure if that will help here.

For more info on the pipeline on Heroku take a look at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

It looks like the easiest way to prevent asset compilation is to put a file in public/assets/manifest.yml - would presume contents is irrelevant but also disable it via config.assets.enabled just in case.

Comment: I've done both but it still tries to compile assets. Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work is to overwrite them in my `Rakefile`:

```
...

Rake::Task["assets:precompile"].clear
   namespace :assets do
     task 'precompile' do
     puts "Not pre-compiling assets..."
   end
end

Rake::Task["assets:clean"].clear
   namespace :assets do
     task 'clean' do
     puts "Not cleaning assets..."
   end
end
```