# How do I delete application.js from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I need to debug some Javascript in a RoR application running on Heroku.  Earlier, I precompiled the assets into a single application.js file and try as I might I cannot remove that file (or perhaps I don't really know how to disable the precompile).  How can I delete application.js on Heroku so I can either debug or determine whether my precompile is still enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable asset pipeline on heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638200/how-to-disable-asset-pipeline-on-heroku)

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to debug locally? And let Heroku do its thing.

Comment: I assume these are rhetorical comments???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by
>   default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by
>   the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in
>   production.

From the Heroku manual.